# will ts2dart continue being maintained?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dart, transpiler

will [ts2dart](https://github.com/angular/ts2dart) continue being maintained?

I'm asking this question for two reasons:

1. The anouncement that `Angular2.dart` will not be transpiled anymore from `Angular2.ts`
2. The project has no new commits since April 30, 2016

Comment: You're probably also looking at the wrong repository: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ts2dart is a TypeScript to Dart transpiler. It's `mainly used to translate Angular 2` from TypeScript to Dart.

This project never was indended to be independent TypeScript to Dart transpiler.
The main goal was to `translate Angular 2` from TypeScript to Dart.

Recently instead of using TypeScript to compile to JavaScript and Dart, the Dart portion will be spun out into its own codebase with its own team (info from https://www.infoq.com).

Also information from Angular blog: http://angularjs.blogspot.ru/2016/07/a-dedicated-team-for-angulardart.html

If you're a TypeScript or JavaScript developer, you'll also benefit from cleaner JavaScript APIs and performance gains as we simplify the TypeScript codebase `to remove the need for compilation to Dart`.

This means that TypeScript to Dart transpiler is no more needed (useless thing).

Comment: It could still be useful for porting Typescript/Angular 2 code to Dart. There are a lot of frameworks popping up now (e.g. Ionic 2), that are Typescript based. Dart users will no longer be able to utilize these easily since the Angular 2 Dart/Typescript split.

Although if ts2dart is no longer maintained, I guess it will become less and less useful.